# where can i download pymongo in 64bit ubuntu/linux

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, nosql

I need to install pymongo in 64bit ubuntu/linux . but the downloads is there only for windows and mac. and this is a production setup.

can anyone knows where to download.

Answer (score 15):

Here's the short answer (tested on ubuntu 12.10, quantal quetzal, 64-bit):

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev
pip install pymongo
```

Comment: +1 But, shouldn't it be `sudo pip install pymongo` in the third line?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to install Python packages is with `pip`. If you don't already have `pip`, please see the instructions on installing it at http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html.

Once you have pip, you can install PyMongo with:

```
pip install pymongo
```

which will download the latest version (currently 2.1). PyMongo uses optional C extensions, so for best performance also install the Python headers and the C build chain. On ubuntu, you can do this with:

```
aptitude install build-essential python-dev
```

If you do this after you install PyMongo, you should then reinstall it, to make sure the C extensions are built:

```
pip install -U pymongo
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out here.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages

Comment: Just download it and you could use `$ sudo apt-get install python-pymongo`